# How can I align an equation with the & placed inside an \underbrace?

Tags: math-mode, align

I have an aligned equation that looks like:

```
\begin{align*}
 1 &+ 1\\
 120 &+ 120
\end{align*}
```

I would like to add an underbrace to one of the lines, but keep the alignment. However, when I do

```
\begin{align*}
 \underbrace{1 &+ 1}_{2}\\
 120 &+ 120
\end{align*}
```

I get errors. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: there are some possibilities here: [Underbrace across align tabs]{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288419/579}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not assume centering, but does assume that `1&+1` and `1+1` are the same width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathllap
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   1 &+ 1 \mathllap{\underbrace{\phantom{1 + 1}}_{2}}\\
   120 &+ 120
\end{align*}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case you've presented, alignment on the `+` symbols is equivalent to simple centering using a `gather*` environment (and no `&` alignment symbols). Thus, you could get your underbrace by writing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*} 
   \underbrace{1 + 1}_{2}\\
   120 + 120
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```