# Brackets in a Permutation

Tags: underbrace, annotations

I'm having a really hard time doing what I thought would be simple.

I have this permutation:

```
\pi=\left(\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\end{array}\right)
```

and I want the sequence 345 to have a brace labelled `$\sigma$` and I need the sequence 678 to have the same thing.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44838/106162)

Comment: @DaiBowen Hello, yes I have already tried it. It doesn't work because my numbers in the bottom row are no longer aligned with the ones on the first row.

Comment: [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288419/underbrace-across-align-tabs) has several possible solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nicematrix`, but

1. the space occupied by the overbraces is not taken into account;
2. we need a trick to move the parenthesis a bit farther from the matrix.

In order to fix point 1, a phantom tall enough is added. For 2, some explicit spacing. I guess you wanted 12 and 6789, in order to single out the disjoint cycles, otherwise it would make little sense.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

Some text to see whether the vertical spacing is good. Some more
text in order to get more than one line. This should be enough.
\[
\pi=\left(\;\begin{NiceArray}{*{9}{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 6 & 7 & 8
\CodeAfter
  \OverBrace[shorten,yshift=1pt]{1-1}{2-2}{\sigma}
  \OverBrace[shorten,yshift=1pt]{1-6}{2-9}{\tau}
\end{NiceArray}\;\right)
\smash[b]{\vphantom{%
  \begin{matrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{matrix}
}}
\]
Some text to see whether the vertical spacing is good. Some more
text in order to get more than one line.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!